# How is the data type and size stored in memory?

Tags: memory-management, assembly, types

```
double a;
unsigned int b;
```

During runtime, how will the OS know how many bytes are affiliated with these variables, and how their bits should be interpreted?  If this is language-/OS-dependent, assume C on Windows.

Is there a LUT that maps bit-representation of variable identifier to byte-size and data type?  From assembly programming on a uC, I recall that the compiler magically knew how many bytes were allocated to a variable, and performed zero-padding/etc appropriately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as the OS is concerned, these are just blocks of memory.  It knows nothing about what they contain, other than "random bit strings".

The smarts are all in the compiler - the compiler tracks the types of variables and then generates load and store instructions for the appropriate number of bytes, and generates code that operates on operands of the appropriate size and encoding scheme (e.g., it knows to use an unsigned add operation instead of a signed one on an unsigned int).

Comment: @sixstring91 just to elaborate a little on Gian's note, which is spot on, in a language such as C, the compiler figures out everything. By the time you have code, the knowledge of what data types are what is essentially all built into the behavior of the machine code at that point. There are no explicit indicators of what a data type is at that level. However, when you get into C++ and other languages that have run-time type checking, objects/classes, etc, structures are setup in memory which tell the software at run time what other types and structures are.

Answer (score 1):

It is language and compiler dependent.  these days an unsigned int is 32 bits, but that is not always the rule it depends on language, compiler and target.  If you were to use an int on an older 8086 or on a 16 bit processor (microcontroller) an int might be 16 bits.  A double is a little more standard.  assuming an IEEE 754 floating point number a single is 32 bits and double 64 bits.  But again it is language, compiler and target dependent.

Then any padding between these if defined back to back like this is also language, compiler and target dependent.  Assuming these are 64 and 32 bits respectively the compiler may not bother to pad anything since the line up nicely on 32 bit boundaries (big assumption there based on the two lines you have provided).  But it may choose to put 32 bits of padding so that both are 64 bit aligned.

Comment: Why on earth is this downvoted?  It's a perfectly reasonable answer.  Upvoting for great justice.